# Deck.gl without React but with webpack is not rendered the specified container

Tags: javascript, deck.gl

The `JS` file looks like this

```js
import { Deck } from '@deck.gl/core';
const HTMLcontainer = document.getElementById('test');
const deck = new Deck({
    container: HTMLcontainer,
    // ... etc
});
```

Then I am using pug for the HTML engine

```
body
        h1 deck.gl
        div#test(class='test')
```

The viz is getting rendered properly, but not within the `<div id='test'></div>` but always in the body.

Does someone know if this is possible when importing deck.gl via webpack but not using React?
Or is there something else wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.

The layers are not placed in a container, but in the canvas. The `container` property is reserved for the map.

The difference is this line

`canvas: 'deckgl',`

Complete solution: slighly different HTML (Pug)

```
div#viz
    canvas#deckgl
```

Some CSS

```
#viz {
  width: 70vh;
  height: 70vw;
  border: 1px solid slategray;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
```

The position is important, because the canvas is has `position: absolute`

And finally the JS

```
const HTMLcontainer = document.getElementById('viz');
const w = HTMLcontainer.offsetWidth;
const h = HTMLcontainer.offsetHeight;

const deck = new Deck({
    canvas: 'deckgl',
    width: w,
    height: h,
    // etc ...
});
```

Now deck.gl is rendering the specified canvas that I can place where I want.

[image]

Comment: And width and height can simply be 100%, no need to get the dimensions from the parent.